# Changing values of a struct passed by reference

Tags: pointers, go

I would like to pass a struct as reference to a function and based on its type, identified by reflection, do the appropriate conversions and store the value in the struct itself.

HOWEVER, although the code runs, and the values are identified and converted inside the function, when the control comes back to function main(), the struct doesn't have the values that I would like to have stored there.

Here is the code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "strconv"
)

type x struct {
    f1 string
    f2 int
    f3 bool
}

func main() {
    s := x{}
    getData(&s.f1, "AAA")
    getData(&s.f2, "1")
    getData(&s.f3, "true")
    fmt.Println(s)

}
func getData(data interface{}, value string) {
    if value != "" {
        switch reflect.TypeOf(data).String() {
        case "*int":
            data, _ = strconv.Atoi(value)
        case "*bool":
            data, _ = strconv.ParseBool(value)
        case "*string":
            data = value
        }
    }
}
```

In this example, I'm getting `{ 0 false}` whilst expecting `{ AAA 1 true}`

Is there any **Golang GURU** that can tell me what I'm doing wrong with this code?

Below the link to go playground 
https://play.golang.org/p/l1_INJLOhAq

Comment: Stop thinking of a pointer as a "reference". It is not and it is not helpful to think a about a pointer as a reference. (What would you call a ***int?)

Comment: Thanks for NOT helping @Volker. Although your point being somehow valid, people that really knows this thing got it first time and wisely spent their time positively trying to help and not criticising. Change your attitude mate, if not keen to help, pass on...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [type switch](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_switches) to execute code depending on the type of the value.  There's no need to use reflection in this scenario.

```
func getData(data interface{}, value string) {
    if value != "" {
        switch data := data.(type) {
        case *int:
            *data, _ = strconv.Atoi(value)
        case *bool:
            *data, _ = strconv.ParseBool(value)
        case *string:
            *data = value
        }
    }
}
```

More information on type switches: [Go Tour](https://tour.golang.org/methods/16), [Go Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_switches), [Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#type_switch).

Comment: Thanks ThunderCat! The type switch was the missing link and the reason I was getting "invalid indirect of data (type interface {})". Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `reflect.Value.Elem()` to get to the actual value rather than the pointer itself.

Here is a quick gist:

```
func getData(data interface{}, value string) {

    switch v := data.(type) {
    case *int:
        val := reflect.ValueOf(v).Elem()
        intVal, _ := strconv.Atoi(value)
        val.SetInt(int64(intVal))
    }
}
```

I suggest you read [The Laws of Reflection](https://blog.golang.org/laws-of-reflection)

Comment: I suggest @ThunderCat's answer which is simpler and better suited for your use case. There is really no need for reflection.

Comment: Thanks weavr. Your solution also works, but indeed the one posted by ThundeCat suits me better. Thanks mate